# PHP Email attachment on open not correctly decoded?

Tags: php, email, pdf, email-attachments

I made two scripts into one script so it did what it needed to be done. But it ain't. Somehow the email attachment part is not working how it should and I have tried numerous changes but can't get it to work.

**The Problem**

In the mailbox the recipient receives the following attachment (filename.pdf.pdf .dat) and this should be filename.pdf

I added below the script that I am using and the html form. From both pages I will only add the code that has to do with the attachment to keep the question more clear.

This is part of send.php:

```
    <form action="send_script.php" method="post" name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div><input type="file" name="fileAttach" value="Zoeken"></div>
    <div><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Verzenden"></div>
    </form>
```

This is part of send_script.php:

```
if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"] != "")
{
    $strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];
    $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"]))); 
}

    ob_start(); //Turn on output buffering 
    --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="<?php echo $strFilesName?>"  
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
    Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="<?php echo $strFilesName?>" 
    <?php echo $strContent; ?> 
    $message = ob_get_clean(); 
    $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
    echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed"; 
    ?>
```

**Edit 1**
The above code is now changed by the help of the below comments thanks everyone for helping me so far. The file is now correctly showing op as test.pdf and the name was test. So that is perfect. The only problem is that it cant be opened it gives the following error.

Error Adobe Acrobat: It was sent as an email attachment and not correctly decoded!

**Edit 2**
Gave up on above code and set on to change the following so it gets a dynamic name and works on pdf.

```
   $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('attachment.zip')));

   --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
   Content-Type: application/zip; name="attachment.zip"  
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
   Content-Disposition: attachment  
   <?php echo $attachment; ?>
```

I changed so far:

```
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"])));
    --PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="eenbestand.pdf"  
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
    Content-Disposition: attachment  
    <?php echo $attachment; ?>
```

The file can now be received and it opens correctly but now for the dynamic name!

Comment: `echo strFilesName` is missing the `$` at the start of the variable name.

Comment: that is a stupid thing to forget. i changed it but it is still not giving me the uploaded file. it gives me now a filename.pdf.pdf .dat

Comment: @HennySmafter Then remove both `.pdf`

Comment: You're catting `.pdf` onto the end of the filename that's coming through $_FILES; you probably don't need to do that. I've no idea where the `.dat` is coming from, though - what's the name of the file you're uploading?

Comment: @andrewsi the name is test so it should return test.pdf

Comment: @HennySmafter Or try removing only the first `.pdf` in `name="<?php echo $strFilesName?>.pdf"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I removed them both and it is showing correctly now but please read Edit 1 above the problem is bigger than I thought

Comment: @HennySmafter You're sure that `test` file is an actual PDF document?

Comment: 10000% when I open it from desktop it just opens and shows with font 70pt TEST. So that is working. Thanks for that input it could have been a damaged file that would have solved it immediately. But too bad it does not.

Comment: Shall I post the entire code it is a long piece of code? Ow I will put it in JSFiddle. It wont work but you can see it in JSFiddle. Here is the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/6USxR/

Comment: @HennySmafter There are many errors in your code (jsfiddle), and would be too much work for me to fix it. I suggest you find another file attachment function that works, then adjust it for your form inputs.

Comment: I sort of gave up hope already by this I have found another options. Can you tell me if this can easily be changed so it uses the filename from the uploaded file i post the code in edit 2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I answer it by simply putting in the right code that did the job for me. Everyone who helped me thanks.

```
    if($_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"] != "")
{
    $strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach"]["name"];
    $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach"]["tmp_name"]))); 
    $headers .= "--".$strSid."\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
    $headers .= $strContent."\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should your `Content-Type` header not be `application/pdf`?

(I would've added this as a comment if I could, as I'm not sure this is correct/relevant.)

Comment: I just tried and it gives than another error: 'Could not open damaged not supported or wrong encoded' But thank you for helping.